# Como obtener los datos de un DataSet usando Entidades en asp.net c# 4 capas

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hola comunidad espero me puedan ayudar con este problema, gracias.

Tengo una aplicación web en 3 capas ademas de la capa Entidades. Quiero obtener los datos de mi usuario usando la capa de entidades para mostrarlos en labels pero no se como comunicarla que ya que en mi acceso a datos solo mando a traer el procedimiento almacenado el cual me retorna un dataset con dos consultas.

Este es mi código de Entidades.

```
    string usuario;
    string nombre_usuario;
    string puesto;
    string roles;


    public string Usuario
    {
        get { return usuario; }
        set { usuario = value; }
    }


    public string Nombre_usuario
    {
        get { return nombre_usuario; }
        set { nombre_usuario = value; }
    }


    public string Puesto
    {
        get { return puesto; }
        set { puesto = value; }
    }


    public string Roles
    {
        get { return roles; }
        set { roles = value; }
    }
```

Este es mi código de Acceso a datos.

```
 public EUsuario Consulta_Datos(string Usuario)
    {
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        DataSet datos = new DataSet();
        SqlParameter sqlparameter = new SqlParameter("@Usuario", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        sqlparameter.Value = Usuario;
        datos = _conexion.ExecuteDataset("bonos.MenuPermisos", sqlparameter); 
        da.Fill(datos);

        return uEntidad;

    }
```

Comment: como es eso de "un dataset con dos consultas" ?

Comment: de donde sale `uEntidad` que retornas como respuesta de  `Consulta_Datos()`?

Comment: Hola @LeandroTuttini gracias pero ya lo he arreglado.

Comment: ok pero asi como lo veo no esta muy bueno ese codigo que has publicado